# console.log in provider not printing

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo app that loads a provider:

```js
export const AppProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  console.log('Hello from app provider!!');
  const alertsBottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  const dismissAlert = useCallback(() => {
    alertsBottomSheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  const values = {
    alertsBottomSheetRef,
    dismissAlert,
  };

  // >>>>> return <AppContext.Provider value={values}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};
```

If I load the app with the last line commented, I can see the console.log. I can also see any changes I made to the console.log.
However, When I uncomment that last line, I don't get any console.logs.
Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I started the server with `expo start` and not `expo start --dev-client`. console logs now appear as expected.

Answer (score -1):

What I think why its not working because the AppContext.Provider is a context provider, and it does not log anything to the console. The purpose of a context provider is to provide data to components that are descendants of the provider. It does not render anything to the screen and does not log anything to the console.

Comment: Interesting. If that is so, do you have a suggestion as to how to debug functions inside the provider then?

Comment: Ya you can try adding console.log statements inside functions and components that are using the context provided by the provider to see if the data is being passed correctly. Or.. maybe  you can use the React native debugger for tht.
Happy Coding :)